# Спрайт теряет качество/расплывается

Tags: unity3d

Спрайт теряет качество/расплывается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я уже нашел ответ на свой вопрос https://www.cyberforum.ru/unity/thread2275407.html

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Дайте на него хотя бы сами полный ответ, иначе он так и будет болтаться пустышкой.